# CSS - What is the meaning of this selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

adfafdadfadsf

```
div.alert.error {
background:url("v3.png") no-repeat scroll 7px -643px #FFEEEE;
}
```

Does the selector "div.alert.error" mean the following?

select DIVs that contain both class alert and error.

Is there a different between

```
CaseI:   div.alert.error
CaseII:  div.alert .error
CaseIII: div .alert .error
```

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
CaseI:   div.alert.error
```

A div with classes `alert` AND `error`. `<div class="alert error">`

```
CaseII:  div.alert .error
```

An element with class `error` that is a descendant of a div with class `alert`.

```
CaseIII: div .alert .error
```

An element with class `error` that is a descendant of an element with class `alert`, that in turn is a descendant of any div.

Answer (score 3):

Let me use your cases as an example:

CaseI: Select each div that has the "alert" and "error" classes applied to it.

CaseII: Select anything that has a the case "error" applied to it that is inside a div with the case "alert" applied to it.

CaseIII: Select anything that has the case "error" applied to it that is inside something with the "alert" class and a div.

Answer (score 2):

The selector means, as you guessed, "select divs that have both alert and error classes."

And yes, there is also a difference between the three cases (already outlined by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568659/css-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-selector/3568684#3568684)). I'd recommend having a look over the [W3C CSS2 selectors document, pattern matching section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, We want to apply the style on  tag. So we should write as following

```
h1(this is called 'selector')
{
    text-align(property):center(value);
    color:green;

}
```

now use of Id selector and Class selector

1) id selector

```
#para1
{
    text-align:center;
    font-face:Bold

}
```

when we want use write like follow:

```
    <input type="text" id="para1">
```